# trying to understand noun + って in this sentence

Tags: translation

> **だいたいスポーツ記者っていったって**、ここんとこスキャンダルの取材ばっかりだ！！

I came up with something like "even though I say I am generally a sports writer", which sounds wrong.

what's tripping me up is the use of だいたい and スポーツ記者って.

Comment: I’m pretty sure 古今とこ is a typo of ここんとこ. I don’t know what つかまえいったって is a typo of, but it must be one.

Comment: ah you're right! I mistyped somehow. I edited the phrase above so it's correct. sorry!

Comment: OK, you should delete 誰か from the question then.

Comment: yep. also adjusted my approximate translation, since I think it may be closer now?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

it seems [noun + っていったって] is a spoken form of [noun + と言っても], which means [even though (I) say "noun"].

and だいたい can indicate the origin of a bad outcome in some cases (like "in the first place")

so the whole sentence would be something like:
[Even though I say "sports writer" to begin with, these days it’s nothing but scandal coverage!]

Comment: You understanding is correct. っていったって could be further contracted to ってったって or even ったって. And だいだい could be replaced with そもそも in this particular context.

Comment: oh wow, thank you very much!

Comment: Here's a challenge for you; a tongue twister
おっとっととっとってっていっとったとになんでとっとってくれんかったとっていっとーと！！！ (need to "get" the hakata/fukuoka dialect - but it means Why could you not save the salty cracker (named "おっとっと") for me when I told you to, that's what I'm saying!!)

Comment: @Jun Sato hahaha that's hysterical